# Two machines serving http for different domains on same ip address?

Tags: apache-http-server, ip, routing

I've got a functioning http server machine on my static IP. I plan to add another one with different capabilities, owners and domain. Both based on apache. Can achieve it? And if yes, would a casual router suffice?

Comment: Incoming packets will likely pick just one machine. You need to add a second external IP address. Where I am, these come as a business package with 6 IP addresses.

Comment: you need to configure your first Apache server as a webserver for the first domain, and also a reverse proxy for the second domain. The reverse proxy setting will point to your second Apache server. Inside this server is the configuration for the second domain. see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this as a home user would be with different external ports on your router.

In port forwarding on your router you would assign the "normal" port, usually port 80, to go to one machine while the other would point at the second machine.

What you end up with would be something like

```
http://your.external.address:80/  --> server1:80
http://your.external.address:81/  --> server2:80
```

Just using `http://your.external.address/` would use port 80 by default and so get `server1`. In order to get to `server2` you would need to specify the different port.

Most casual home routers do allow this level of port forwarding.

Comment: But maybe I can do this:

http://first.external.address:80/  --> server1:80
http://second.external.address:80/  --> server2:80?

Or maybe a trick with SSL?
http://first.external.address:80/  --> server1:443
http://second.external.address:933/  --> server2:443?

Comment: If you have two external addresses and are running both servers on the same machine or different machines then sure. You don't mention what you are actually doing in your question.